# query-string pick method returns the first match from a filter and corrupted URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, query-string, querystringparameter

I am trying to clean a URL and only keep some parameters that I need in order to parse them
so I was using pick method providing it the url, and the filter which is a regex test method
here I am testing to check if the key in the query parameter matches the regular expression

```
const groupRegex = new RegExp('^(GRP_)[a-zA-Z0-9/-]','g');
export const parseGroups= (url:string)=>{
    let pickedURL = qs.pick(url,(key,value)=>groupRegex.test(key));
    console.log(pickedURL);
}
var url=`http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob[]=SW&GRP_sa[]=QW&GRP_sa[]=AA&projects[]=MP,PM&releases[]=2021.4,2022.1`
parseGroups(url)
```

for example `http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob[]=SW&GRP_sa[]=QW&GRP_sa[]=AA&projects[]=MP,PM&releases[]=2021.4,2022.1`
it should return `http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob=SW&GRP_sa=QW&GRP_sa=AA`
yet it only tests for the first request parameter only and logs
`http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob%5B%5D=SW`

I am trying to clean the url from any other parameters that doesn't match my regular expression
so I can parse the URL and extract the object
so it can be like this for example

```
{
       GRP_Bob:["SW"],
       GRP_sa:["QW","AA"]
 }
```

Instead of having other parameters parsed also which are not necessary. I know I can just parse the url normally, and then loop on the  returned `query` object, and remove any key that doesn't match the regex, but is there anything wrong I am doing in the above snippet?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the filter function to be `(key,value)=>key.startsWith('GRP_'))`

```
export const parseGroups= (url:string)=>{
    let pickedURL = qs.pick(url,(key,value)=>key.startsWith('GRP_'));
    console.log(pickedURL);
    let parsedURL = qs.parseUrl(pickedURL)
    console.log(parsedURL.query)
}
var url=`http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob[]=SW&GRP_sa[]=QW&GRP_sa[]=AA&projects[]=MP,PM&releases[]=2021.4,2022.1`
parseGroups(url)
```

and the `pickedURL` logged this `http://localhost:3000/tat?GRP_Bob%5B%5D=SW&GRP_sa%5B%5D=QW&GRP_sa%5B%5D=AA` which is likely to be correct.
it came out like that

```
GRP_Bob[]: "SW"
GRP_sa[]: (2) ['QW', 'AA']
```

So I am confused actually what's going on with the regular expression approach, and why the keys in the second approach have `[]` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yeh! This one is a rare gotcha and totally unexpected every time I see it. `RegExp` actually has state. See [Why does JavaScript's RegExp maintain state between calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688518/why-does-javascripts-regexp-maintain-state-between-calls) and [Why does Javascript's regex.exec() not always return the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477415/why-does-javascripts-regex-exec-not-always-return-the-same-value).

In your case, you don't need the `g` flag, so removing that should also fix your problem since that makes the regex stateless.

Comment: Thank you so much @Adam Thomas. It actually worked and returned the expected output which is `GRP_Bob[]: "SW" GRP_sa[]: (2) ['QW', 'AA']`, yet the keys still have `[]` in it which I don't understand, do you have any idea?

Comment: I opened an issue on `query-string` for this part. you can check my first comment regarding the `[]` part https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string/issues/344

Comment: Well, I solved it by passing an options argument like this `let parsedURL = qs.parseUrl(url,{arrayFormat: 'bracket-separator', arrayFormatSeparator:','})`

Comment: I still have no idea why `pick` method converts `[]` to `%5B5D`