React hooks and comparing object references
I have fallen into the too-many-rerenders trap while implementing my own hook. The hook itself looked like this:
function useRegexValidate(value: string, regex: RegExp, errorMessage: string, deps: any[] = []): ValidationResult {

    const [result, setResult] = useState<ValidationResult>(ValidationResult.Valid);

    useEffect(() => {

        if (!regex.test(value)) {

            setResult(new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage));
        } else {

            setResult(ValidationResult.Valid);
        }
    }, [value, regex, errorMessage, ...deps])

    return result;
}

It was kind of tricky to find, but the source of error was passing regular expression as RegExp. During every render a separate instance of RegExp object was created, thus causing a re-render, during which another instance was created - and so on.
I solved this problem by passing the regular expression as a string:
function useRegexValidate(value: string, regex: string, errorMessage: string, deps: any[] = []): ValidationResult {

    const [result, setResult] = useState<ValidationResult>(ValidationResult.Valid);

    useEffect(() => {

        let regexObj = new RegExp(regex);

        if (!regexObj.test(value)) {

            setResult(new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage));
        } else {

            setResult(ValidationResult.Valid);
        }
    }, [value, regex, errorMessage, ...deps])

    return result;
}

I guess I could also solve it by not passing the regular expression in-place, but instead creating a constant value (since the expression is unlikely to change), e.g.
const regex: RegExp = /.../;

useRegexValidate(..., regex, ...);

This would hinder user-friendliness of my hook though, because one would need to remember to call it in a specific way not to cause hard to track bug. So that's definitely not an option.
I don't really like the solution I chose, because the RegExp object needs to be created every time the validation is performed. Is there a way to somehow teach React to compare specific objects' contents instead of merely their references?
Is there a better way to fix my initial code?

Could you use the string of the regex as the dependency, to make it stable? Fundamentally two different RegExp objects aren't identical, or even equal, whether or not they represent the same pattern.

Right. Regex also can hold state (something that is often surprising when you come across it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688518/why-does-javascripts-regexp-maintain-state-between-calls). So the string of the regex is the true "input" to this hook. Bit of a side point but likely this effect and the useState for result probably should not exist. That is a computed value from other state, and the whole thing should ideally by a single useMemo. See https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#caching-expensive-calculations

Destructure the RegExp to the source and flags properties. Use them as the dependencies for the useEffect, and then rebuild the RegExp:
function useRegexValidate(value: string, regex: RegExp, errorMessage: string, deps: any[] = []): ValidationResult {
  // destructure the regex to strings
  const { source, flags } = regex;

  const [result, setResult] = useState<ValidationResult>(ValidationResult.Valid);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentRegex = new RegExp(source, flags); // rebuild the RegExp
    
    if (!currentRegex.test(value)) {
      setResult(new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage));
    } else {
      setResult(ValidationResult.Valid);
    }
  }, [value, source, flags, errorMessage, ...deps]) // use source and flags as dep

  return result;
}

However, as adsy suggest, since the result is a computed value, you don't need to cause a re-render by using the useState and useEffect combo. It's better to just compute it, and if it's a costly computation, wrap it in useMemo:
function useRegexValidate(value: string, regex: RegExp, errorMessage: string, deps: any[] = []): ValidationResult {  
  return regex.test(value)
    ? ValidationResult.Valid
    : new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage);
}

Or wrap with useMemo() if needed:
function useRegexValidate(value: string, regex: RegExp, errorMessage: string, deps: any[] = []): ValidationResult {
  // destructure the regex to strings
  const { source, flags } = regex;
  
  return useMemo(() => 
    new RegExp(source, flags).test(value)
    ? ValidationResult.Valid
    : new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage)
  , [value, source, flags, errorMessage]);
}



because one would need to remember to call it in a specific way

Well, of course. This is React, it is a responsibility of the developer to keep track of everything. That is why useMemo, useCallback and the dependency array exist
You can use a library like yup to help you validate
If you don't want to use library, for your problem, you might not need an effect
const regexValidate = (value, regex) => 
 regex.test(value)

You don't need effect, you don't need state, you don't need custom hook, you don't even need an utility function. Just validate it in the body of the component const error = regex.test(value) ? '' : errorMessage
Validating it on each render is probably way more optimized than calling useEffect on each render.
There is a compiler for react, that I think is not stable yet, but it might help you with the keeping the reference of the regex between the renders

There is no reason to use state for this... This is a classic case of deriving state. The proper way to implement this is with a memo:
export const useRegexValidate = (
  value: string,
  regex: string,
) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    const regexObj = new RegExp(regex);
    return regexObj.test(value);
  }, [value, regex]);
};

Though even this memo is probably overkill and you can just recompute the validation on render.
